# PREVENT FLASK CACHING

Tags: python, flask, caching

I am working on a site based on flask based on:

- nginx as a webserver
- gunicorn as a WSGi for flask,
- supervisor as a process manager for  gunicorn,
- flask as the web framework,
- mysql and sqlalchemy as the data base layers.

I made a simple page thats loads a json that resides in the database, and renders it to generate a web page. so far nothing complex.
The problem tthat i had is that this web page is cached and i'm serving the same content, no matters if the json changes.

My page has the meta headers to prevent caching so it is not the browser.
I configured my virtual host on nginx to prevent caching.
I tagged the session on SqlAlchemy with expire_all() to avoid caching on a data base layer.

So... i'm assuming Flask is caching my content. The problem is that i've already configured my flask app to prevent caching but it doesn't seems to work.

Did anyone had the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
nginx: no cache

add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
```

Flask App:

```
from flask_caching import Cache
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = False
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
app.config['CACHE_TYPE'] = 'null'
cache = Cache(app)
```

Comment: We need to see the complete Python code. One possible problem can arouse if one mixes up compile and runtime

Answer (score 0):

I' finally could solve the problem,

1 first by preventing the worker from catching the content:
--max-requests=1
2 implementing gevent to let the system accept more request per seconds, as cached content were disable,
3 increment sqlalchemy max connections per database. as data content will be queried each time for eah request